# Overriding dimens.xml values of a library

Tags: android

I have an apklib which has a dimens.xml in it with some default values, but I want to use some other values based on my use-case. Is there any approach to do this without modifying the source of the library?

Comment: did you end up finding anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to touch the source code just define the values with same name in your dimens folder. When you use same name, it is always count the `overridden` values. I think it will work.

Another approach may work like this way, get the `viewgroup/layout` from your library, iterate the `ChildView` and change the `margin/padding` as your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

late to the party but it will probably useful for other users:

you simply need to override the value in your dimens.xml inside app/src/main/res/layout/